# Delphi DrawThemeBackground on timage causing white background

Tags: delphi, themes

I want to use Windows's native look and I am trying to learn how to do it.

I am trying to paint timage.canvas with Windows toolbutton background but the background of timage seems White and it doesnt seem same as Windows,
how can i fix that?

here is my code;

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  theme: HTHEME;
begin
  theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'TOOLBAR');
  // error checking omitted for brevity
  try
    DrawThemeBackground(
      theme,
      Image1.Canvas.Handle,
      TP_BUTTON,
      TS_HOT,
      Image1.ClientRect,
      nil
    );
  finally
    CloseThemeData(theme);
  end;
end;
```

here is the picture of result when i applied theme on timage:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask for a 'BUTTON' theme, not 'TOOLBAR' if you want a button.

```
theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
```

Also this line should come before the `try`.

For a list of theme parts and states [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210(v=vs.85).aspx)

From the above list you will see that the `iPartId` and `iStateId` you used are not the right ones (although worked). I would suggest `BP_PUSHBUTTON` and `PBS_HOT` instead.

```
procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  theme: HTHEME;
begin
  theme := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'BUTTON');
  try
    DrawThemeBackground(theme,
                        Image1.Canvas.Handle,
                        BP_PUSHBUTTON,
                        PBS_HOT,
                        Image1.ClientRect,
                        nil);
  finally
    CloseThemeData(theme);
  end;
end;
```

**Edit** Here's an image just for comparison of a `TToolButton` on a `TToolBar` in Windows 7:

[image]

As you see the `TToolbutton` (on `TToolbar` at the top) when 'hot', doesn't have the bluish appearance as a `TButton`. Beneath the toolbar are your code on the left and my suggestion on the right. Is it the difference in lightgray / white or lightgray / bluish you ask about?

Comment: Thank you very much tom, asking for a 'BUTTON' solved my problem as you described